# Split the data across multiple columns in student Table using pl/sql or sql

Tags: oracle, plsql, plsql-package

Please help me. Currently I’m working on pl/sql procedure.  In sport table has ID and for same id has multiple codes. I need to split these multiple codes and insert them to student tables as code1,codes2,code3.

**Source table**

```
ID  CODE
----------
222 4wta
----------
223 5qer
----------
222 5qer
-----------
224 3der
---------
```

**Desired table**

```
ID  CODE1   CODE2   CODE3
-------------------------
222 4wta    5qer    NULL
-------------------------
223 5qer    NULL    NULL
------------------------
224 3der    NULL    NULL
------------------------
```

Comment: ___Desired table___ is the result you want to get from a SQL query, correct? I mean, it is not a database table, is it?

Answer (score 1):

With a little help of analytic function (to decide which `CODEn` to fetch) and aggregation, you'd have this (presuming that there are max 3 codes per each `ID`).

Sample data:

```
SQL> select * From src;

        ID CODE
---------- ----
       222 4wta
       223 5qer
       222 5qer
       224 3der
```

Inserting:

```
SQL> insert into trg (id, code1, code2, code3)
  2  with temp as
  3    (select id, code,
  4       row_number() over (partition by id order by code) rn
  5     from src
  6    )
  7  select id,
  8    max(case when rn = 1 then code end) code1,
  9    max(case when rn = 2 then code end) code2,
 10    max(case when rn = 3 then code end) code3
 11  from temp
 12  group by id;

3 rows created.
```

Result:

```
SQL> select * From trg;

        ID CODE1 CODE2 CODE3
---------- ----- ----- -----
       222 4wta  5qer
       223 5qer
       224 3der

SQL>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your prompt reply. I really appreciate your time.But my desired table has more than 10 fields and 4 fields for code1...code4. For other fields I retrieved data from different tables and assign new variable names to them. for example select desc, subject,id into temp_decs,temp_sub ,temp_id from subject where id=a.id. After retrieving all the required data insert them into new table. So i'm not sure whether it is work or not. But Ill try this code.Thanks again!

Comment: I tried the code. but it didn't work. please tell me what this "temp" is? when I run I got following error.SQL Error:ora-00936:"missing expression"

Comment: SRC in the answer above would translate to your sports table... TRG would translate to your Student Table... temp is what is called a CTE (https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/mysql-8.0-en/with.html) that takes the data from the sports table and reorganizes it so that you can select what you need out of it.

Comment: Anu, we know what you tell us. There's no sign of "10 columns and 4 codes and different tables" etc. in your question. Anyway: if you can create a SELECT statement that returns data you want, it is a simple task to convert it to INSERT. The rest of your question has been answered by @Shaun (thank you, Shaun).

Comment: Thanks Shaun and little foot!